# Function for averages of tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tuples, average

I have a string, dictionary in the form:

```
('the head', {'exploded': (3.5, 1.0), 'the': (5.0, 1.0), 
"puppy's": (9.0, 1.0), 'head': (6.0, 1.0)})
```

Each parentheses is a tuple which corresponds to (score, standard deviation). I'm taking the average of just the first integer in each tuple. I've tried this:

```
def score(string, d):
    for word in d:
        (score, std) = d[word]
        d[word]=float(score),float(std)
        if word in string:
            word = string.lower()
            number = len(string)
            return sum([v[0] for v in d.values()]) / float(len(d))
        if len(string) == 0:
            return 0
```

When I run:

```
print score('the head', {'exploded': (3.5, 1.0), 'the': (5.0, 1.0), 
"puppy's": (9.0, 1.0), 'head': (6.0, 1.0)})
```

I should get `5.5` but instead I'm getting `5.875`.
Can't figure out what in my function is not allowing me to get the correct answer.

Comment: You have `return` statements in a `for` loop in a function for calculating an average. Also, the result depends on the order of the iteration over the dict. Clearly, something is wrong. Hint: you are mixing calculating separate terms and the whole answer. Looking at separate words in a loop you should be getting their contributions to the score, not the final answer.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to get `5.875`?  `3.5 + 5.0 + 9.0 + 6.0 / 4` is `5.875`...

Comment: @zigg No, it should be `5.5` because for the given string `'the head'` `5.0 + 6.0 / 2` is `5.5`

Comment: Oh, okay, I see now.  It wasn't clear to me from your description what you were trying to achieve—I assumed you were just ignoring the strings much like you were ignoring the second halves of the tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def score(s, d):
    included = [d[word][0] for word in d if word in s]
    return sum(included) / float(len(included))
```